# Distribution question Discrete Math

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can we distribute 20 balls into 5 distinct boxes when it is required that no box remain empty and box number 2 will have no more than 10 balls?

Can someone explain me the steps to answer this question?

Thanks

The final answer should be 19choose4 - 9choose4, if you can explain why it would really help.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be rephrased as the number of non-negative integral solutions to the system:

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=20\\1\leq x_1\\1\leq x_2\color{blue}{\leq 10}\\1\leq x_3\\1\leq x_4\\1\leq x_5\end{cases}$$

Approach with [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  First find the number of solutions where you ignore the upperbound on $x_2$.  Then subtract away the number of those solutions which were bad, i.e. the solutions where instead $11\leq x_2$.  Find the number of those by perhaps using a change of variable.

---

*Edit:* Since the OP edited his question after my post was already made, he apparently didn't fully understand.  Further, since the OP already has the answer and just doesn't understand it, I feel confident that this isn't for a test, so will elaborate.

The number of ways of distributing $A$ b**a**lls into $O$ b**o**xes (*I'm using $A$ and $O$ in order to hopefully avoid the confusion caused by using $n,k,r$ as different articles use these for different things*) where each box gets at least one ball can be seen via [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to be $\binom{A-1}{O-1}$.

Alternatively worded, the number of positive integer solutions to the system $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_O=A\\1\leq x_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$ is again $\binom{A-1}{O-1}$

We can see this by laying the balls out in a line (*the stars*).  We then choose where to place dividers (*the bars*) between the balls to denote which balls will go into which box.  Note that the condition that every box gets at least one ball makes it so that the dividers must be placed in different locations.  For small example, with $5$ balls and $3$ boxes we could have $\star\mid\star\star\mid\star\star$ denoting that the first box gets one ball while the second and third boxes both get two.  As there are $A-1$ spaces between the balls and we wish to place $O-1$ dividers, we arrive at the result.

---

For your specific problem, if we temporarily ignore the upper bound, we have $20$ balls and $5$ boxes, each box must get at least one ball.  By using the logic above, this gives us $\binom{20-1}{5-1}=\binom{19}{4}$ outcomes.

Some of these are bad however in that they violated the upperbound we ignored earlier.  I.e. they are those outcomes corresponding to solutions to the system

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=20\\1\leq x_1\\11\leq x_2\\1\leq x_3\\1\leq x_4\\1\leq x_5\end{cases}$$

(*Note, I use here $11\leq x_2$ rather than $10<x_2$ to keep things consistent.  Since we were looking specifically at integer solutions, these are effectively the same*)

By changing variables, letting $y_i=x_i$ for $i=1,3,4,5$ and by letting $y_2=x_2-10$, we get that this is equivalent to the system:

$$\begin{cases}y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=10\\1\leq y_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$$

which is again in the form that we know how to deal with, having $\binom{9}{4}$ solutions.  Remember again these are the *bad* solutions that we needed to remove from our earlier calculation to account for the upper bound.

This gives us a final calculation of

$$\binom{19}{4}-\binom{9}{4}$$

Comment: This is the explanation I was looking for! I am studying for the final exam and I have issues with this kind of question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a more complex way of doing this using generating functions, but simply speaking if there are $f(n,k)$ ways to distribute $n$ balls into $k$ boxes without restrictions, you have 11 cases.

Case $x$ is, the special box #2 will contain exactly $x$ balls, with $x$ an integer in $[0,10]$.

1. Find the desired number of ways in terms of $f(n.k)$ for each case.
2. Compute $f(n,k)$.
3. Add the $11$ cases to get your answer.